# Number of inversions in $S_n$

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-groups, coxeter-groups

I have a problem about some result appearing just before the proposition 1.5.2 in *Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups* by Bjorner, Brenti. It's about the inversions in $S_n$.

I don't understand why 1.26) is true.

[$\text{inv}(xs_i)=\text{inv}(x)\pm1$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uf4K.png)

I can understand why we lose/add the element $(i ,i+1)$, but I'm not sure why the we keep the same number of inversions. For example if $(p,q)\in [1,n]^2\backslash \{i,i+1\}$ with $p<q$, it's ok since $s_i:=(i,i+1)$ won't move them (as stated by David, these are generators of $S_n$)

Now suppose that $(p,q)\neq (i,i+1)$ but they have a factor in common, namely either $p=i+1$, or $q=i$. In this case it's not clear why $s_i(p,q)$ is still an inversion of $x$.

Comment: what is $s_i$? $ $

Comment: @Exodd one of the standard Coxeter generators of $S_n$, in particular it is the transposition $s_i=(i,i+1)$.

Comment: suppose $p<q$ and $q\in \{i,i+1\}$, $p\not\in \{i,i+1\}$. If $(x(p),x(q))$ was an inversion, than also after $s_i$ it still is an inversion. And it is an iff. And it works even for $p,q$ exchanged

Comment: in formulae, if $p<i$, then $$x(p)<x(i)\iff x(p)<x(s_i(i+1))$$ where $s_i(p) = p$ and $p<i+1$. The same works with $i+1$ instead of $i$, and viceversa with $i<p$

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why it shows that if $(p,q)$ is an inversion in $x$, then $(s_i(p),s_i(q))$ is an inversion in $x$. If we take $q=i$, we have $x(p)<x(q) \iff x(p)<x(s_i(i+1))$ but we remain with $i+1$. So $(p,q)$ is not an inversion iff $x(p)<x(s_i(i+1))$ and it's enough ?